# Gmail API - How to set from name (PHP)

Tags: gmail-api

I need to set From name on GMAIL API.

When i use the following condition client receives only the first name before "@";

```
$message = $serviceGmail->users_messages->send('me', $message);
```

Eg.: If my mail is test@email.com, the mailbox receive on "from name" only "test"

I already setted on smtpmailer fromName but it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure? have you tried expanding the email in the Gmail client? Your email address should be there as well as your name.

Comment: Everything works fine in the following methods: - reply to, attachments, subject, but SetFrom does not work... Gmail-api uses the 'me' parameter or auth email. And its exactlly what appears on another mailboxes. if you set the "setFrom()" on phpmailer it doesnt respect this parameter

Comment: Share your $message content. At least the email headers portion.

Comment: $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->SetFrom($from, $fromName);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $fromName); 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        $mail->AddCC($cc);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body; 
        $mail->preSend();
        $mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
        $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $data = base64_encode($mime);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data); // url safe
        $message->setRaw($data);    }

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Try using your email address instead of 'me'. That'll fix it.